# VB.NET ~ I have my app fixed to give me all img src tags for a website. But the one tag I need is not listed in the results

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

The img src that I need to grab is:

```
div id="recaptcha_image" class="width: 300px; height: 57px;" style="width: 300px; height: 57px;">
<img width="300" height="57" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuvlvMA4JvVIQvDR4C_iDbOTwOF5FUIRPGkkSImDRYAD6sY2L0IxyJSpSP1WGjWqr0MQ-dmjkiIgevFY2gkMpNWi1cQbtgUZB5QaYr_vIHv6xFzG9ydFbBWs4xiEhWoxHEFUYHZj6CCh4obyZSOd2La0nozLZw" style="display:block;">
```

Here is my code that grabs all the img src tags from any website. The one thing is the img src that I need isn't listed in the returned results.

How can I correct my code to grab only this one field? Here is my working program...currently is doesn't load a pic into the picturebox...but it does return the results in the rich text box. Thanks

```
Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text

Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
Dim doc As HtmlDocument = hw.Load(s)

Dim items As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
If items Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("There is nothing to show you")
End If
If items IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each item As HtmlNode In items
        RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox2.Text & (item.GetAttributeValue("src", "value") & Environment.NewLine)
        'PictureBox1.Load(item.GetAttributeValue("src", TextBox1.Text & "value"))

    Next
```

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack doesn't implement XPath as per the W3C XPath Spec. -- therefore this question doesn't qualify to be tagged as "xpath".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the complete HTML it is difficult to say, but if you want the `src` for this specific `img` you can use the following in `SelectNodes` (which should probably be changed to `SelectSingleNode`).

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='recaptcha_image']/img[1]").Attributes("src").Value`

The above will return the `src` String for the `img` tag.

Comment: When I use your code I am now getting these errors. Here is a screen shot of my screen.  [link]http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1310/errorjxe.jpg[/link]

Comment: I edited the `["src"]` to `("src")` (C# instincts :)). Also, the line returns the `src` string not an `HtmlNodeCollection`, but `Items` is defined as an `HtmlNodeCollection` so you get an error. You can also just replace your `"//img"` with `"//div[@id='recaptcha_image']/img[1]"` in your original code but that is a bit more lengthy for the same effect.

Comment: If that XPath expression doesn't work then you will need to post a link to the page or a more complete snippet of HTML.